# How can I get the path of the dumpfile I've opened in Windbg?

Tags: directory, windbg, dump, pykd

I'm opening dumpfile in `Windbg`, and I'm writing a `PYKD` related Python script for working with that dumpfile. Now I'd like to create a file in the directory of that dumpfile, and the name of that file should be based on the dumpfile I've just opened.

In order to do this, I'd simply need to know the path of the dumpfile I've opened, but I don't find the basic `Windbg` command nor the `PYKD` command to get this.

How can I get the path of the file, I've opened in Windbg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 >>> targetSystem().desc
 u'64-bit Kernel bitmap dump: C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\000030a40_memory.dmp'
```

desc returns the same string as ||

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a specific PyKD command, but you could always use `dbgCommand()` and then use a WinDbg command.

`||` should give you the needed information:

```
0: kd> ||
.  0 64-bit Kernel triage dump: F:\some\path\test.dmp
```

Please note that `||` shows the system status and may have multiple lines if you're debugging multiple systems at once:

```
||1:1:012> ||
   0 64-bit Kernel triage dump: F:\some\path\test.dmp
.  1 Live user mode: <Local>
```

It's likely not applicable in your case.